# What's the best way to handle authentication when deploying app engine apps from Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: google-app-engine, hudson, jenkins

I'm able to deploy my App Engine project from the command line using appcfg.sh without a problem.  I'd like to get this to work in Jenkins but the problem is the deploy utility prompts for my Google password.  I can pass in the email using the --email parameter but there's no way to pass in the password (please don't suggest using --passin b/c that's not what it's for).

The best case senario I can think of is that when someone runs the Jenkins job it asks for the username/password then and runs the deploy using that.

But I'd settle for any way to get it working at this point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind your password to be visible in plaintext, this is what I use on my build XML to auto-deploy my app from Jenkins:

```
<target name="update" 
        depends="enhance" 
        description="Uploads the application, including indexes">

        <java classname="com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg" 
              inputstring="<YOUR_PASSWORD>" 
              classpath="${appengine.sdk}\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar">

              <classpath>
                  <fileset dir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
              </classpath>
              <arg value="--email=<YOUR_EMAIL>" />
              <arg value="--passin" />
              <arg value="update" />
              <arg value="war" />
        </java>
</target>
```

Where appengine.sdk points to your GAE folder, i.e.
`<property name="appengine.sdk" location="D:\libs\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.1"/>`.

Comment: If you setup 2Factor authentication for your Google account, you can additionally generate a password you will use for deploying only and which you can invalidate at any time without affecting your real password.

Comment: @koma: yes, you are right, and I think nowadays Google will ask for the generated password by default when using the appcfg instead of asking our real password.